# UINavigationController custom LabelView when pushing a new view Controller onto the stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` all set up with my initial view controller, which allows a user to input a value. It also has a custom UILabel as the `titleView`, so that i can display a totally 'flat' navbar with green text.

Then, when they press a `UIButton`, it pushes a new view onto the stack, which obviously eradicates the `UINavigationItem` that carries my custom titleView.

My question is: how do i continue to use a custom view for the `titleView` of the navigation bar reliably?

I've obviously tried using the class' `delegate` methods (`willPush` and `didPush`), but the first obviously doesn't have the `topItem` yet, so it ends up adding my UILabel to the current `navigationItem`, and `didPush` there is a visible delay between the view controller animating in, and the new `titleView` label being applied.

I've tried and googled a lot, but nothing seems to be working quite right, i'd prefer not to lose the animation when pushing new view Controllers.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Posted a rough outline example of my code below, it's not 100% perfect because it's an overview of what i'm doing, rather than a paste directly from XCode.

```
// This code lives in the app delegate

// Set up the root view controller that needs to be contained
UIViewController *myFrontView = [[MYFrontViewController alloc] init];

// Set up the uinavigationcontroller
UINavigationController *myNavController = [[MYNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myFrontView];

// Customise the initial UINavbar titleView:
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithText:@"My custom text"];

// Change the text Color.
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

// Set my new label as the custom titleview.
[myNavController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView: myLabel];

// Boilerplate code to make myNavController the rootViewController of the window etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are setting the `titleView` of the `UINavigationController`. This will only temporarily change the current title view.

To properly change the title view, use the `titleView` property of the `UINavigationItem`. The navigation controller framework will take care of setting up the views of the `UINavigationController` based on the current navigation item for you, and will also make sure animations are smooth.

Comment: I'm setting the titleView on the navigationBar.topItem, which is an instance of `UINavigationItem`, isn't it?

Comment: When are you doing this? In most cases, the best way would be to use the titleView outlet in the storyboard, if possible.

Comment: I'm constructing most of my views in code, and setting the titleView just after `alloc`ing the view controller using the `initWithRootViewController:` method.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but you should not init the UI in the init method, try to do it in `viewDidLoad` instead (otherwise you might indadvertedly load views prematurely). I just created a minimal example and it works, would you care to show your code?